# delete similar value in firebase in two different users

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Actually I am trying to delete a group member that should be deleted within all the users present in database. I tried to delete value using DatabaseReference with `datasapshot.getref().removeValue()`.But the main problem is this delete should also reflect in the others  users account. I am trying to delete in other account but its not working

```
Query query = fbData.limitToFirst(1);
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

     dataSnapshot.getRef().removeValue();

     for(DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
         //String email = (String) child.child("EmailId").getValue();

           String key = child.getKey();
           Log.e("the value",child.getValue().toString());
           //DatabaseReference dbref =fbData.child(key).child("Groups").child(value).removeValue();
                        child.child(key).getRef().removeValue();
       }
 }
```

My database values look like

[image]

Here in the above imageevery user consist of groups and list of members.For eample If a user naming sankar@gmail.com wants to exit from group the entire group should get deleted from his account and his name in another user group should also get deleted similar to WhatsApp group concept. Thanks in advance

**Update**

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String email = (String) dataSnapshot.child(keyUser).child("EmailId").getValue();
            Log.e("user mailid to delete",email);
            for(DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                String key = child.getKey();

                firebaseDB.child(key).child("Groups").child(value).child(email).removeValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in the way you add data, in the same way you should remove it. Unfortunately, there is no remove method that searches through all your records in the database and removes the fields that belong to a particular user. You need to do it yourself.

Seeing your database structure, i recomand you make a change. In stead of using something like this:

```
first
 |
 --- 0: emailZero
 |
 --- 1: emailOne
 |
 --- 2: emailTwo
```

Use this structure:

```
first
 |
 --- emailZero: true
 |
 --- emailOne: true
 |
 --- emailTwo: true
```

In this way you can simply remove the `emailZero` from your database.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Cant we iterate all the users using the key and delete the value from the group?

Comment: Yes you can. You first need to get the email addresses and based on them, delete every record that is related to user. The structure above, will help you achieve that.

Comment: I tried some code which is shown in my question using for loop but its not working.. any help!

Comment: Your code will not work if you don't do some changes. As i said before, changing the database structure will help you achieve that. You can get the email address and use it directly in your `DatabaseReference` and in the end just use removeValue() method.

Comment: In the above code I had commented one line `DatabaseReference dbref =fbData.child(key).child("Groups").child(value).removeValue()`here value refers to email address

Comment: In order to remove a field, you need to remove it by key, not by value. You need to use something like this after you make the changes: `fbData.child(key).child("Groups").child("first").child("sakar@gmail.com").removeValue(‌​)` instead of ``fbData.child(key).child("Groups").child("first").child("0").removeValue(‌​)``

Comment: Thanks.. Now I have the value i.e  mailid but how to get the key of that mailid?

Comment: You can using getKey() method but that's why i said to use the email address as a key and not as a value.

Comment: I had updated my question with some code kindly please reply me How to place the key in place of the value(email)..

Comment: This not what i meant. You need to change the database structure and the code accordingly. Not only the code.

Comment: I don't have access to change the structure of database so I am working on it. Is their any possibility to get the key of the value(email) and delete it

Comment: No, there is not. Not with your code and database structure. Trust me, it would be better if you will change it. So having the email as key, you can perform a remove operation very easy.

Comment: Tell me approach to change my code accordingly to perform remove operation

Comment: Using this database structure, there is no way. Make the changes and your problem will be solved.